# Edit/Rename ListView item label name in WPF for In-place Editing

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I would like to know how can I edit or rename the name of a ListView item label in WPF([Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idxxF.png)).

If this is possible, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You are obviously coming from a Winforms background where editing the label of a `ListViewItem` is built in.

*WPF does not have this built in functionality, so you have to implement it yourself.*

The regular `GridViewColumn` tag gives a non editable column.
Since you want to edit this field you should use a a `TextBox` in a `CellTemplate`.

Example:

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox Width="40" Text="{Binding FieldName}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```